# Setting up Pyspark for Jupyter Notebook: mismatch worker and driver python versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm having a difficult time setting up and using pyspark locally.

I have a conda environment that my jupyter notebook is associated with.
Below is what I've typed into terminal after installing pyspark through terminal.

```
pip install pyspark
pip install findspark

which python3.6

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON= #results from 'which python3.6'
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=#results from 'which python3.6'

python --version
# result: Python 3.6.12 :: Anaconda, Inc.


java -version
# java version 1.8.0_25
# SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)

pyspark
#... spark version 3.0.1, using python version 3.7.4 (deffault)
```

Here is the code in jupyter notebook that I'm trying to get to work:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

try:
    conf = pyspark.SparkConf().set('spark.driver.host','127.0.0.1')
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext(master='local', appName='samsApp',conf=conf)
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    print("Binding")
except ValueError:
    print("Spark session already created")

# below code from stack overflow: how to create pyspark dataframe
cSchema = StructType([StructField("WordList", ArrayType(StringType()))])
test_list = [['Hello', 'world']], [['I', 'am', 'fine']]

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(test_list,schema=cSchema)

df.show()
```

The last line above (df.show()) yields an error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, macbook-pro, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/j.doe/anaconda3/envs/package_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 477, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.7 than that in driver 3.6, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions. Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

How should I fix this? I don't know how to adjust the worker vs driver version.
Please give advice, I'm not seeing straightforward answers that have worked for me online.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=<python path>
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=<jupyter path>
pyspark
```